# Actualizar actividade vindo do AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

Sempre que clico na Toolbar tenho um menu que ao clicar numa das opções me aparece um `AlertDialog`. Esse AlertDialog tem um `setSingleChoiceItems`, em que o user ao escolher uma opção e ao clicar no OK, essa opção fica gravada na BD. 
Tudo isto funciona bem. O problema é que ao voltar para a actividade eu quero q apareça diferente informação consoante a escolha que o user fez no AlertDialog e não estou a conseguir.

Estou a usar o OnResume()

```
    mes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textMes);
    metaDef = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textMetaDef);
    despesa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDesp);

    if (db_helper.hasMoeda()) {
        moeda = db_helper.getMoeda();
    } else {
        db_helper.updateMoeda("Euro");
    }

    Gasto gasto=new Gasto();
    gasto=db_helper.getGasto();

    mes.setText(gasto.getMes());

    if (moeda.equalsIgnoreCase("Euro")) {
        metaDef.setText("" + gasto.getMeta() + " €");
        despesa.setText(String.format("%.2f €", gasto.getDespesa_final()));
    } else if (moeda.equalsIgnoreCase("Real")) {
        metaDef.setText("R$ " + gasto.getMeta());
        despesa.setText(String.format("R$ %.2f", gasto.getDespesa_final()));

    }
```

O que está a acontecer é que a actividade não se actualiza quando clico no OK do alertDialog. 
Alguem tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: É um *AlertDialog* ou um *DialogFragment*?

Comment: @ramaral , AlertDialog..... AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

Comment: Então você deve actualizar a informação da *Activity* no método `onClick()` do botão *OK* do *AlertDialog* e não no `onResume()`

Comment: @ramaral, o meu AlertDialog esta noutra classe, nessa classe eu tenho um onClick mas é para validar a opção que user escolhe. O problema é q eu quando saio do AlertDialog queria que me fosse feito uma especie de refresh na actividade...daí usar o onResume()

Comment: Em qual outra classe? Outra *Activity* ou uma classe que herda de *AlertDialog*. Por favor reformule a pergunta de forma a ter toda a informação.

Comment: a informação escolhida no dialod deve refletir na activity... é isso? escolhe no dialog e muda algo na activity ao fechar o dialog... é isso?

Comment: @FlipNovid ao clicar no Ok do AlertDialog quando volto a actividade deveria mostrar uma determinada informação q nao mostra...(no AlertDialog o user escolhe  a moeda...quando volta para a Actividade deveria executar a parte do codigo if (moeda.equalsIgnoreCase("Euro").... e nao executa)

Comment: vc deve fazer uma call back no seu dialog.. jah fez isso antes? quer que eu poste aqui? assim no retorno do seu do seu dialog ou em seu clique muda o valor na activity

Comment: qdo é fechado o dialog a activity ou fragment nao esta entrando no seu onResume...isso é claro

Comment: @FlipNovid obrigada, vou investigar! :)

Comment: @porthfind consegui solucionar?

Comment: @FlipNovid vou ver este fds

Comment: @porthfind ok... qualquer coisa chama aqui... que eu posto um exemplo... posta se conseguiu

Comment: @FlipNovid podes por exemplo pf? Não consigo solucionar o meu problema :\